# Insert and Display data SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, methods, insert, information-retrieval

I am having problem with my insert statement in my application.

```
public void insert() {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

   cv.put(Training_table.KEY_ACTIVITY,"Swimming");

}
```

I know I have to add a .insert line but I cant get it write, I have tried this as a solution to no avail:

```
public void insertRecord() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Training_table.KEY_ACTIVITY,"Swimming");
    db.insert("Get info from db", null, cv);
    db.close(); }
```

I am unsure as to what the first parameter should be after db.insert??

Below is the getAllData method which is simply designed to retrieve the insertion "Swimming" into the KEY_ACTIVITY row and display it in a text view. (The class for this is further below.

```
public String getAllData(){
    //SQLiteDatabase db = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {KEY_ROWID, KEY_ACTIVITY};

    Cursor cursor=ourDatabase.query(Training_table.DATABASE_TABLE,columns,null,null,null,null,null);

    StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
    //Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        int cid=cursor.getInt(0);
        String activity=cursor.getString(1);
        buffer.append(cid+" "+activity+"\n");
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Below is the class where I call the methods and set the text in the xml text view to the content in the getAllData string.
It is not updating the text view, it’s just blank and doesn’t show any errors. Can you see any standout issues with the code??

```
public class Training_table_view extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.training_table_view);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTTinfo);//setting up reference
    Button bv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bViewDetails);

    Training_table info = new Training_table(this);//create training table

    info.open();//open Training table  class
    //info.insertRecord();
    info.insert();//insert data (currently PK id and activity name


    String data = info.getAllData();//return string from get data method


    info.close();

    tv.setText(data);//set text view to the string we got data from


}//onCreate
```

}//Training_table_view class

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated as I know the solution is something quite trivial. Kind Regards,
Conor

Comment: First parameter is the table name.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter in db.insert() is the table name where you save your data. You can easily use your String Training_table.DATABASE_TABLE:

```
db.insert(Training_table.DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
```

Alltogether your method "insertRecord()":

```
    public void insertRecord() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Training_table.KEY_ACTIVITY,"Swimming");
        db.insert(Training_table.DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        db.close(); 

}
```

Please be sure that you call the method "insertRecord()" and not the method "insert()"

Comment: ta! problem averted. it seems i didn't need the db.close(); at the end either

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in db.insert() is the **table name** as

```
insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
```

So change

```
db.insert("Get info from db", null, cv);
```

to

```
db.insert(TableName, null, cv);
```

Note : replace **TableName** with your database table

For more info see  [SQLite insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

Comment: @user3872519 Happy to help,enjoy coding.